# Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK Core Assemblies .NET Core Porting Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dynamics-crm

When trying to use [Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK Core Assemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/) in a .NET Core 2.0 project, the following error occurs at runtime simply by `using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk`:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataConversionError' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

It looks like the Core Assemblies (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client) may simply not be compatible with anything other than ~net4x.

Is there any obvious way to get around this error or load the WCF `System.ServiceModel` class/interfaces needed by `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` in the context of target `netcoreapp2.0`? Is it possible to use 
[Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) to bridge the gap? It looks like the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility pack [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) indicates **Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)** classes/interfaces are "available". How can I use the compatibility pack to perhaps load `System.ServiceModel.Description`?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: SDK definitely is not compatible with dotnet core.
Why wouldn't just taget 4.5.2? Or consider 3rd party Dynamics WebApi  helpers\proxies such https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI

Comment: The goal was to take advantage of the performance and portability of .NET Core as a microservice. CRMWebApi and ADAL may simply not be an option asthe target CRM is not on Azure Active Directory.From what I can find a client credentials flow would only be possible in conjunction with Azure Active Directory in the context of Dynamics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried all possible things and can say that SDK, ServiceModel etc are not compatible with .net core and never will be, according to multiple discussions on github. However, i was able to do this:

- Use XrmToolBox and crmsvcutil.exe to generate models (optional)
- place them in netstandard2 project
- reference XRM SDK from nuget
- SDK works under .net core in part where LINQ queries and raw QueryExpressions are translated to subclasses of OrganizationRequest
- write custom IOrganizationService which serializes OrganizationRequests and sends them to some other app
- Other app is .net core web api which references that project and XRM SDK, but runs on **full framework on windows** and executes actual requests, serializes responses and sends them back.

IMPORTANT EDIT:
I found out that SDK 2016 doesn't work reliably in .net core on linux due to various reasons, and stopped at 2011 (nuget package is `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.2011`). It works fine except in one case: whe you do `context.AddObject` and pass an Entity **with no ID**. SDK relies on p/invoking native Windows library to create sequential UUID and crashes on Linux. You can overcome this by setting ID prior to calling `.AddObject()`.

Comment: As for adding reference to web services - did you try to create new `.NET Standard` library, add reference to `Connected Services`,  and then reference your library in `ASP.NET Core` project?

Comment: i tried adding connected services and it fails because they rely on Service Model too

Comment: if by "web services" you mean new odata web api which is available in CRM 2015/2016, i did not try it because our company has CRM 2013 only and odata support there is very limited.

Comment: I used the way way to connect to kind old `WSDL` web services (means generate proxy classes) from `.NET Standard` library, which I referenced and used then from my `ASP.NET Core` project.

Comment: Can you add more details on how to accomplish these steps?  I don't see how you can reference the XRM SDK from a netstandard project.  Also, your last step says "other app is .net core web api"...should that be .NET framework?  Seems like a typo.

Comment: You just reference nuget package i mentioned. It warns you that it may not work, as usual with other nuget packages which do not target netstandard. Just ignore the warning. And the latter thing, i am just used to call projects with controllers and without pages as web api. Sure it is not *that* web api from the past, i meant aspnetcore application with http api. Which targets netcore, but runs on full framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it got resolved when I selected template Console Application (.Net Framework) in Visual Studio instead of Console Application (.Net Core).