# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Development Setup

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Development(Salesforce Developer) and am trying to figure out how to setup my development environment for creating plugins and UI components and deploying them to the CRM Cloud version. Based on what I read, I have tried setting up Visual Studio but cannot use the SDK on Mac since it required windows..

Is it possible to do this type of development on Mac without a VM? Can someone point me in the right direction for setting up the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics 365 SDK targets full .Net Framework 4.6.2 which isn't available for Mac.
Also there are great amount of community tools that facilitate development for D365. I would ballpark estimate that 99% of them won't be able to run on Mac.

Thus yes, you won't be able to develop efficiently directly on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has annouced/preview mode of CDS (common data service ) SDK for .net core.

But note this is currently in alpha version and not even in Beta. so lot of things will change. Also you will have to be have crm online I believe to use sdk for .net core.

[dynamics sdk for .net core](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Announcing-the-net-Core-SDK-for-Common-Data-Service-CDS-External/td-p/470035)

In addition check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247981/5436880) with which tries to circumvent .net framework for dynamics sdk.